# Why is zero-initialization not the default for non-initialized variables in c++? Is there a compiler option to force it?

Tags: c++

In most languages I know, scalar-type variables are zero-initialized by default, if they were not initialized in the code.
Why doesn't this happen in c/c++? The only reason I could think of is performance, but

- is it really that performance-consuming, if I do initialize it?
- is it preferable to have undefined behavior?
- if I want to avoid undefined behavior, I have to initialize it anyway, so what did I win?

Wouldn't it be easier to explicitly tell the compiler somehow not to zero-initialize a variable, if this might be a performance issue?

An finally my question:
Is there a gcc option to tell the compiler to zero-init by default?

Comment: "The only reason I could think of is performance" Right so if you're writing a graphics driver; and you're using an extra cycle per pixel; performance is rather important isn't it?

Comment: 0 doesn't magically solve the issue either. A bug from an uninitialized variable is still a bug in the many cases where 0 isn't what you wanted. Undefined behaviour lets a sanitizer find it.

Comment: So why do other languages do it?

Comment: Yes, initialising (large) variables of automatic storage duration hits performance, and it is undesirable to have different rules for different size variables.   It is also unnecessary if, as often happens, the first operation on that variable is to assign a value (initialising to zero first doubles up the cost).  Even worse, those operations will happen every time the relevant block is entered (unlike variables of static storage duration, which will only be initialised once in the program lifetime).    gcc does not have options to zero-initialise automatic variables.

Comment: @Ben "Other languages" are not always as "safe" as they advertise ;-)

Comment: Other languages try to avoid UB. In most cases, 0 either works as desired or doesn't cause massive problems. That's not to say C++ needed this as its default or that other languages couldn't still let you opt into something more "tracked". In fact, Java comes with some static rules for determining whether a local variable has been assigned and refuses to compile if it isn't 100% sure that the variable has an explicit value. That in its own right is useful, and can be replicated through static C++ checkers, but also comes with the caveat of sometimes being unsure when you _are_ sure.

Comment: @Ben Undefined behavior seems to be an unpopular design choice for programming languages. For those languages that do not have it you need to describe a behavior for pretty much everything. That means if the language allows you to declare variables without specifying an initial value, the language needs to describe exactly what that variable's value is (or how it behaves if it never gets a value). It's usually simpler from a language design stand-point to just say it's zero initialized and it seems most languages opt for that choice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One of the founding principals of c++ is to not force developers to pay for what they don't use. If you write something like `int x; x = 1;` then you shouldn't have to pay for the zero initialization of `x`, even if that cost happens to be very tiny.

Edit : Regarding your other two points

> is it preferable to have undefined behavior?

Undefined behavior is not necessarily a bad thing to have in the language (you can argue both ways). It's definitely a bad thing if you write code that causes it. Notably it gives more freedom to implementers and  enables important optimizations.

> if I want to avoid undefined behavior, I have to initialize it anyway, so what did I win?

It's not undefined behavior to have an uninitialized variable. It's undefined behavior to try to read from one.

Comment: I think the answer misses the fact that *implicitly* giving a zero value to variables does not necessarily prevent bugs. If the standard mandated zero initialization, compilers would have to assume that users can and will rely on it, and stop warning in places where it's obvious the variable should have been initialized to a significant value

Answer (score 5):

**The down-side**: Potential errors because of uninitialized values.

**The up-sides**:

1. Efficiency. You don't pay for it if you don't need it.
2. The compiler doesn't add assumptions about the right init value. Per @chris in the comments to the OP, you can get a false sense of security since 0 is not always the right initialization value. If it should start as -1, then 0 is wrong.

**The mitigations**:

1. Use constructors to initialize your non-POD types
2. Use "[Almost Always Auto](https://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)" to enforce initialization at declaration time. (Or as @Peter notes in the comments, use explicit types but don't declare a variable until you can properly initialize it. This is implied by AAA, but AAA makes it harder to get wrong since you can't accidentally forget to initialize because the initialization carries the type information also.)
3. Crank up compiler warnings. For gcc, use `-Wall -Werror`, which includes `-Wuninitialized` and then will error on uninitialized values.

**The origin**: In the hoary old days of C, all declarations came first before initialization. Compare [this example from the K&R book](https://github.com/caisah/K-and-R-exercises-and-examples/blob/master/04.02-functions_returning_non_integers/ex-primitive_calculator.c):

```c
int main(void)
{
  double sum, atof(char s[]);
  char line[MAXLINE];
  int getline(char line[], int max);

  sum = 0;
  while (getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
    printf("\t%g\n", sum += atof(line));
  return 0;
}
```

C++ retained compatibility with C in this regard, but that came with what is an unfortunate default behavior.

Comment: chris comment below the answer made me think... automagically initializing everything does actually not really solve errors due to uninitialized memory. If you know how to properly initialze it you can do it already now. Just saying, nice answer, +1

Comment: The mitigation I prefer, which is supported in C++, is to not define (create) the variable until information needed to initialise it is available, and then explicitly initialise it in the definition.  That completely avoids any problem with uninitialised variables of automatic storage duration

Comment: @Peter: Agreed. That is implied by the "Almost Always Auto" mitigation, but one can do it with explicit type names to get the same benefit.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with zero initializing variables automatically is that not all your variables should have zero as their initial value. If you *forget* to initialize a variable with its correct value, the compiler can easily warn you that you used an *uninitialized* variable.

However if the compiler initialized every variable to zero whether it was your intention or not, then you would never know when you forgot to give them their correct value because the compiler would be unable to tell you.

Example:

```
std::string some_input = "27";

// ...

int i;
std::istringstream(some_input) >> i; // give i a value 

// ...

std::cout << "stuff: " << i << '\n'; // use i here
```

Now what if I forget to give `i` a value?

```
int i;
// whoopsie I forgot to give i its value 

// ...

std::cout << "stuff: " << i << '\n'; // COMPILER WARNING uninitialized!
```

Now what happens if the compiler (or I) zero initializes it?

```
int i = 0;
// whoopsie I forgot to give i its value 

// ...

std::cout << "stuff: " << i << '\n'; // oopsie, output the wrong value, undetectable!
```

Zero initializing can seem like your friend but, if the variable should not contain zero, making it zero is giving it the **wrong** value. That is a silent corrupting influence on your data that is hard to spot.

Comment: The compiler could still warn even if it did zero initialise.

Comment: @eerorika How would the compiler know you didn't want the value zero? I don't see how the compiler can warn you unless it warns you **every time** you use the compiler generated zero value - which defeats the point doesn't it?

Comment: How does it defeat the point? The compiler could still warn in exactly the same cases where it now warns. But instead of warning about UB, it would warn about using implicit zero. The point is to not have UB - it is not defeated.

Comment: @eerorika Whether the compiler assigns a zero value or not does not change the compiler's ability to warn you that you did not set it yourself. If the compiler is going to issue a warning regardless then what is the point in setting it to zero? You are never going to use the program with the compiler assigned value because it warned you and you fixed the problem. So your way the compiler generates less efficient code for zero advantage.

Comment: @eerorika no it cant - it can't tell the difference between "the programmer wanted a zero value and so didn't do anything" and "the programmer wanted a non zero value but forgot"

Comment: @Galik The point is to not have UB. The compiler cannot detect all possible cases of uninitialised variable, so it would be possible for it to occur when the program is executed. If it couldn't ever happen, then it would be pointless to discuss whether it should have UB or not.

Comment: @eerorika UB is neither better nor worse than a corrupted value. In fact UB may present in more cases than a corrupt value. And, frankly I don't know that a compiler could fail to detect uninitialized values.

Comment: @MikeVine Of course it can tell the difference: `int a = 0; cout << a;` The compiler can know that the programmer intended 0. `int a; cout << a;` The compiler can know that the programmer failed to set the value explicitly -> It should warn.

Comment: @eerorika But in this case `int a; cout << a;` what would be the point in the compiler setting `i` to zero before telling you you had a problem?

Comment: @Galik Knowing that "output could be either correct, or zero is much more useful than "output could be either correct or maybe there isn't output or perhaps the process crashes or leaks personal information and increases the radiation dosage to lethal levels etc."

Comment: @eerorika Crashing is the best thing that can happen. Outputting false data that is indistinguishable from true data is the probably worst thing that can happen.

Comment: @eerorika And, of course, the compiler warned you so you avoided UB regardless.

Comment: @Galik zero can be distinguishable data in some cases.  I agree it being a bad thing.  I disagree that being worst thing. UB can be worse: See the earlier comment about lethal radiation dosage.

Answer (score 0):

> is it really that performance-consuming, if I do initialize it?

Performing zero initialisation is potentially more performance-comsuming than not performing it, yes.

> is it preferable to have undefined behavior?

It is preferable to let the programmer decide whether they want performance (no zero initalisation before assigning the value later) and potential for UB in case of a bug or whether they want deterministic behaviour upon such bug (by explicitly value-initialising even when it is unnecessary).

At least, it was preferred by the people who designed C++ (and C before that). I'm sure it is still preferred by many who choose to use C++, considering there exists languages which don't have UB that could have been chosen instead.

> if I want to avoid undefined behavior, I have to initialize it anyway, so what did I win?

Sometimes you don't have the value to which the value should be initialised to until after the object is created. In such case, you can assign the value later. By not initialising to zero, you win not having to set the value more than once.

Answer (score 0):

> is it really that performance-consuming, if I do initialize it?

Tiny overhead is still overhead, hence yes it is.

> is it preferable to have undefined behavior?

If the alternatives are worse performance or declaring something as not valid code then yes it is preferable to declare wrong usage as undefined behaviour.

> if I want to avoid undefined behavior, I have to initialize it anyway, so what did I win?

Usually you declare variable only when you use them, but consider this contrived example

```
int a,x;
if (some_condition) {
    x = foo();
} else {        
    a = foo();
    x = foo(a);
}
return x;
```

It is a bit contrived (you would probably declare `a` only when you need it), but if every variable would get initialized, then this code would suffer some overhead for no good reason.

Comment: I realise your example is contrived, but it can be simplified to `int x = foo(); if (!some_condition) x = foo(x);  return x;`   or to `return some_condition ? foo() : foo(foo))`   - and the question of initialisation to zero is moot in both cases.

Comment: @Peter I am too much used to declare stuff only when I can initialize it, so I really have a hard time to come up with a good example ;)

Comment: @Peter anyhow, no matter how contrived the example is, I see no reason to penalize it by initializing `a` (or `x`) when it is not needed at all

Answer (score 0):

I personally would find this useful - as a convenience - if it was optional.  Perhaps:

```
class MyClass
{
    ...
} = 0;
```

Then, for example, if I add members to my class, I don't have to mess around zero initialising them.

Answer (score 0):

These are from C++ Core Guidelines:

- ES.20 : Always initialize an object
- ES.21: Don’t introduce a variable (or constant) before you need to use it
- ES.22: Don’t declare a variable until you have a value to initialize it with

More can be found [here](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#S-expr).

As far as I know, global variables will be explicitly 0, but locals will have a different value (in case of a bool variable, this will lead to true).

Visual Studio(just an example), in DEBUG mode, explicitly initializes variables to given values(which can be noticed easily, usually cause an out of bound error or access violation). In RELEASE mode, memory is not explicitly initialized and it just keeps the content that was there before.